# the requested URL cannot be found when the file name contains accents or special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I am trying to upload 2 files using the post method with the following names:

- 8torío 2022 (24).pdf
- tstión ar_BO ().jpg

Both contain an accent, but uploading them throws me the error:

> "requested url cannot be found"

When I remove the accents these files upload without problem.

1. What could be the problem?
2. Is there a setting in the web.config that I can fix it with?

In advance thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: So the spaces in the filename don't bother you? ))

Comment: Maybe you need to check if your application is set to use UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

It would be ideal if you could share your Upload code, so that we can see exactly what you're doing now, however have you considered ***URL Encoding*** your file names and renaming the file that will be saved as the Encoded Name to handle accents?

Here is a sample, taking your strings above, removing the spacing and then encoding them, however as I said, without seeing your code, I can't comment how exactly it would fit in to your solution.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string val1 = "8torío 2022 (24).pdf"
            .Replace(" ", "");
        string val2 = "tstión ar_BO ().jpg"
            .Replace(" ", "");
        
        string encodedVal1 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(val1);
        string encodedVal2 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(val2);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Value 1: {encodedVal1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Value 2: {encodedVal2}");
    }
}
```

Output

```
Value 1: 8tor%c3%ado2022(24).pdf
Value 2: tsti%c3%b3nar_BO().jpg
```

[MS Learn: URL Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-6.0)